# I cannot donate in clan castle war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I cannot donate in clan castle war, I have tried it many times, I have even uninstalled the Clash of Clans application several times and restarted my mobile device many times.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a dedicated clash of clans tag here, what made you think the minecraft tag was the appropriate one to use?

Comment: Are you in the war? if not, you will not be able to donate.

Comment: Does it say you are a spectator ?  Does it say the war has already started?  Are the CCs full ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/943498-ONE-ONLY-thread-Cannot-donate-to-War-Castles-game-crashes-%28known-bug%29?p=6063678&viewfull=1#post6063678).

The issue appears if you have **barracks** (normal or dark) or **spell factory** in the process of an upgrade.

A workaround would be to cancel the upgrade, finish it with gems, or wait till the upgrade is finished.

I had this problem when I had a barrack in upgrade while trying to donate in the war map. The app crashed. When the barrack was finished upgrading, I was able to donate in the war map again.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot donate in any way in the war cc's you're probably not **IN** war. You could be a war spectator. Otherwise, the castles might be full or the war has started, as mentioned by @ZeroStack

Answer (score 0):

No, there's a glitch where only some people can donate in war castles, even if they are in war. It is crashing the app. This came from the TH11 update. They broke war.

Comment: citation needed